# Searching for a tag without brackets doesn't recognize the tag

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, search

I normally search for questions tagged with [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) and related. So, I typically search for `sql-server`, `sql-server-2008` without using brackets and it automatically understands that I'm searching for those tags. Strangely, when I do the same with `sql-server-2012`, it doesn't recognize it as a tag unless I search with the brackets, here is an example:

[image: screen shot]

Why does this happen?, shouldn't it recognize it as a tag just like `sql-server-2008`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is done if the word is used for a tag which is between the 60 most popular tags. In the other cases, the brackets are not automatically added.

This is what the Search Options page says:

> Results are weighted heavily towards question title matches, and any search terms matching the most popular 60 tags will be automatically mapped to a tag to help narrow your search.

Comment: Oh, that explains it then, thanks!